# retrofit - get response error in string

Tags: android, rest, http, bad-request, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to consume my REST api.

I keep getting `400 bad request` from my server, and I can't parse the error to a string.

When I tried to POST from **POSTMAN** chrome application, the request is successful and I get `201 created` response (new user).

**here are my dependencies:**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
```

**here is my interface:**

```
public interface PingMeApi {

    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: text/html"})
    @POST("/users/")
    Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);

}
```

**here is my POST request:**

```
Call<User> call = pingMeApplication.apiService.createUser(user);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        /// How can I parse the response here????

        String result;
        try {
            result = response.errorBody().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {


    }
}
```

I can't seem to parse the response on `onResponse` so I cant understand what the error is.

it says on the docs - http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en that if I get and error, `onResponse` will be called and I can see the error string in `response.errorBody().string()`, but its an empty string.

any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        User user = response.body;
        Log.e("User name", user.getName()); // do whatever you want
    }else{
        Converter<GlobalErrorObject> converter =
                        (Converter<GlobalErrorObject>) GsonConverterFactory.create().get(GlobalErrorObject.class);
                try {
                    GlobalErrorObject globalErrorObject =  converter.fromBody(response.errorBody());
                    Log.e("Error", globalErrorObject.getErrorMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }
}
```

** In my case GlobalErrorObject is a pojo representing JSON as :

```
{
   "errorCode": "API_INVALID_TOKEN",
   "errorType": "API_ERROR",
   "errorMessage": "Valid API Token required."
}
```